# Can amp-sticky-ad show up on page load?

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible to have amp-sticky-ad show up on page load rather than having to scroll down for it to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [amp-sticky-ad document](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-sticky-ad) states that

> -The sticky ad will appear on the bottom of a page.
>
> -The sticky ad will display after scroll one viewport height from top provided there is at least one more viewport of content available.
>
> -When scrolled to the bottom of the page, the viewport is automatically padded with the additional height of the sticky ad, so
> that no content is ever hidden.

Nowhere does it state it'll run on reload page. So, NO.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is the tricky to perform fast loading.
The browser can render the screen and the sticky-ad load after scroll down.